# Shortening jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

In short, the code picks up to 9 different `id`s from `li` in `jailplayer`.

If a hillside, it shall save the value of the id, and then checks if there are more `li`, up to 9 pcs.

Then I save this in an array, depending on how many `id`s were found.

This looks like a mess.  Can someone help me shorten this code and make it easier to read?

```
if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 1) {
                var player1 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(1)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player1;

            } else {
                var player1 = '';
            }
            console.log('done one, searching 2');

            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 2) {
                var player2 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(2)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player2;

            }else {
                var player2 = '';
            }
            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 3) {
                var player3 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(3)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player3;

            }else {
                var player4 = '';
            }

            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 4) {
                var player4 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(4)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player4;
            }else {
                var player4 = '';
            }

            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 5) {
                var player5 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(5)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player5;
            }else {
                var player5 = '';
            }

            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 6) {
                var player6 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(6)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player6;
            }else {
                var player6 = '';
            }

            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 7) {
                var player7 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(7)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player7;
            }else {
                var player7 = '';
            }

            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 8) {
                var player8 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(8)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player8;
                player8 .= ',';

            }else {
                var player8 = '';
            }

            if ($("#jailplayer").children("li").length >= 9) {
                var player9 = $("#jailplayer").find("li:nth-child(9)").attr("id");
                sender = sender + ',';
                sender = sender + player9;
            }else {
                var player9 = '';
            }


            console.log('adding ize');


            var ize =[sender];
```

Comment: We can help you shorten and clean up your code, but we could do a much better job if you can explain the objective of the code.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Also, if you could show a sample of the HTML you are searching through, that would help too.

Answer (score 8):

It appears that you're just trying to create a list of players from the id values on a list of `<li>` tags and also build a comma separated list of those ids.  If that's the case, you can do the entire code block like this:

```
var players = $("#jailplayer > li").map(function(index, elem) {
    return this.id;
}).toArray();
var sender = players.join(",");
```

Note: this doesn't populate variables `player1`, `player2`, etc...  Instead, it puts the players into an array where they are likely easier to deal with later.

---

Also, it is unclear what you are trying to do with this:

```
var ize = [sender];
```

If you explain the purpose of that, we could offer help on whether that's the right way to to it.  Storing an array of a single value that's a comma separated string list of values seems a bit odd which is why I ask.

---

Key concepts here:

`$("#jailplayer > li")` - get all the desired `<li>` tags into a jQuery collection so we can iterate over them.

`.map()` - iterates over a jQuery collection building a new jQuery object containing the values that the callback returns.  Note, the callback will be passed `this` as each successive element in the original jQuery collection and the id value can be referenced simply as `this.id`.

`.toArray()` - get the array out of the jQuery object that was returned so you have just an array, not a jQuery object any more.

`.join(",")` - take all the elements of the array and join them into a string with the passed in separator between them.